# Crystal Report. The System cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, crystal-reports

When I click to load the receipt. It shows Load report filed and the inner exception as:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

What could be the issue? Earlier it was working but now it is showing problem.

```
public static void loadBillReport(ReportDocument rd, CrystalReportViewer crv, Int32 status, Int32 orderID)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getOrderReport", MainClass.con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderID", orderID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                rd.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Reports\\billreports.rpt");
                rd.SetDataSource(dt);
                crv.ReportSource = rd;
                crv.RefreshReport();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (rd != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    rd.Close();
                }
                MainClass.showMessage(ex.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear and indicating that the file can't found. Please check that billreports.rpt file exist on the path where code is expecting.

Comment: yes it is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably not finding the file here:

```
rd.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\Reports\billreports.rpt");
```

Make sure the file exists and the user which is running the program has access to the file via security permissions.

Also, is the rpt file a part of the build? (bin\release) or (bin\debug)?

Maybe the compiled version isn't finding it.

You can change the relative path to absolute path (D:\your\path\Reports\billreports.rpt) and test this theory.

Comment: check the user permissions need to run your application. try running it as administrator and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
Exception thrown: 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException' in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
Exception thrown: 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException' in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
Load report failed.

Answer (score 0):

Manually copy .rpt .cs report files and crystalreportviewrs13 folder to Root folder i.e

> C:/inetpub/wwwroot/{ProjectName}